# Can Voldemort kill Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

We know, Lily made a sacrificial shield for Harry. So, Voldy can't kill Harry with the killing curse.

What would have happened if Voldy used non-magical things to kill him? Like take a 9mm bullet and fire it straight, or stab him. Or kill him like he killed Snape...

Is this all possible? Then, why didn't he use them? Was he a fool?

See this as well --> [Why bother with Unforgivable Curses?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55234/why-bother-with-unforgivable-curses)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't muggle-born wizards use Muggle technology to fight Death Eaters?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/why-dont-muggle-born-wizards-use-muggle-technology-to-fight-death-eaters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be answered through evidence shown in the books or other sources but I do lack on pottermore knowledge.

We know Voldemort would not use a pistol it is much too muggle(Yes it's a measurement now) for him, he would despise the very idea of resorting to a muggle invention to fulfil his needs. I'm not even sure if he would consider it anyway much like dumbledore states with sacrificial magic:

> "But I knew too where Voldemort was weak. And so I made my decision. You would be protected by an ancient magic of which he knows, which he despises, and which he has always, therefore, underestimated — to his cost. I am speaking, of course, of the fact that your mother died to save you. She gave you a lingering protection he never expected, a protection that flows in your veins to this day."

From this you can gather that if he despises something ultimately he disregards it and in turn underestimates it's usefulness.

He may think of slitting his throat with a knife much akin to how the oldest Peverell brother died. It isn't extremely muggle but it is definitely not magical. Voldemort is out to be the most powerful **Wizard** afterall.

We do know that if Voldemort was to touch harry he would be exposed to excruciating pain this is evidenced through what happened to Quirrell when he was merged with Voldemort. That may transcend into knife wounds and would most certainly hurt Nagini.

It would be however silly to think that he could send Nagini out to kill HP as this he clearly would have considered although I am not too sure as to whether he would use her to kill HP. Definitely wound and entrap until such time as Voldemort arrived himself. Think of the scene in Godrics Hollow.

We do know that the Basilisk was immune to the effects of the sacrificial protection though but he is an incredibly powerful dark creature.

Although by the time that Voldemort was actually ready and able to kill Harry he was immune to the magic of the Sacrificial Protection anyway. As he used Harry's blood for the body build spell he could touch and harm harry without consequences.

> Harry showed them both the place where his robes were torn, and the cut beneath them.
>   ‘He said my blood would make him stronger than if he’d used someone else’s,’ Harry told Dumbledore. ‘He said the protection my – my mother left in me – he’d have it, too. And he
>   was right – he could touch me without hurting himself, he touched my face.’
>   [...]
>   ‘Very well,’ [Dumbledore] said, sitting down again. ‘Voldemort has overcome that particular barrier. Harry, continue, please.’
>   *Goblet of Fire* - page 604 - Bloomsbury - chapter 36, *The Parting of the Ways*

May I also point you towards a question that features a Brilliant answer from DVK on how Voldemort is a highly functioning psychopath: [What caused Voldemort to become so Evil, or is his villainy 'inherent'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54967/what-caused-voldemort-to-become-so-evil-or-is-his-villainy-inherent/54968#54968)

Comment: _the most powerful Wizard afterall_ We can't neglect the fact that he is mad for killing Harry with his own hand in anyway possible. That's why he is fishing great wizards like Grindelwald for information like where is the Elder wand and all...

Comment: Actually, it was because of the magical protection that Voldemort couldn't touch Harry. When Voldemort was ressurected with Harry's blood, he could touch Harry just fine (see book 4, as well as the movie)

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I said. @Andreas

Comment: @Simon You said 'with evil intentions'. It's not so much the evil intentions, as it is the fact that Voldemort was 'fused' to Quirrel, making Quirrel also vulnerable to the magical protection. Intend itself had nothing to do with it. The magical protection is only against Voldemort, not against others.

Comment: @Andreas Hmm good point, I think the "evil intentions" part is somewhere in the back of my head I'll have to do some digging although I feel you are right.

Comment: @Simon Others with evil intentions (like Barty 'Mad-Eye' Crouch) could touch him just fine. When Harry returned after Voldemorts ressurection, Crouch could touch him just fine, even though he intended to kill Harry once they were isolated from the others and Harry had been questioned.

Comment: @Andreas True, will edit now.

Answer (score 1):

We know that in *The Cursed Child* That Voldemort does find a way to kill Harry.

> Have you swallowed something funny in there? Become a Mudblood without any of us noticing? Harry Potter died over twenty years ago as part of that failed coup on the school — he was one of those Dumbledore terrorists we bravely overthrew at the Battle of Hogwarts. Now come along — I don’t know what game you’re playing but you’re upsetting the dementors and entirely ruining Voldemort Day.

Comment: You know I hate to say it but your answer technically is right...but to see that quote is - well I'm not even sure what to say about it. On the other hand it's debatable that it is an answer because CC is entirely different and perhaps not what the questioner had in mind? Either way I personally believe that if you could find a way to have more than a sentence that isn't hidden it would improve the quality of your answer.