# In the alternate reality during CURSED CHILD, how could Harry have been killed?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, we find out in an alternate reality, Harry died at the Battle of Hogwarts (at least I think it was the Battle of Hogwarts). But how? Didn't Harry's blood run through Voldemort's veins along with his mother's protection, therefore tethering him to life as long as Voldemort lived? Here's a direct quote from *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*:

> "He took my blood," said Harry.
>
> "Precisely!" said Dumbledore. "He took your blood and rebuilt his living body with it! Your blood is in his veins, Harry, Lily's protection inside both of you! He tethered you to
>   life while he lives!"

Unless Voldemort never took in Harry's blood in the alternate reality, Harry should not have been able to die, correct?

Comment: Spoiler in question. Thank you :,(

Comment: Also, Harry was master of Elder Wand...

Comment: Avada Kedavra? Well that and it's CC...

Answer (score 7):

### Because things are complicated

It is true that Harry survived in part because of Lily's protection, Voldemort having taken it into himself, and of course his own possession of the Elder Wand. However, Rowling [is](http://web.archive.org/web/20120214193440/jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=122) very explicit: **Harry still could have died.**

> It is important to state that I always saw these kinds of magic (the
>   very deepest life and death issues) as **essentially un-scientific**; in
>   other words, **there is no “Elder Wand + Lily’s Blood = Assured
>   Survival” formula**. What count, ultimately, are Harry and Voldemort’s
>   own choices. They have each been given certain weapons and safeguards,
>   but the power of these objects and past happenings lie in how they are
>   understood, and how they are used or enacted upon. Harry has a deeper
>   and truer understanding of the meaning of the objects and past events,
>   but his greatest powers, those that save him, are free will, courage
>   and moral certainty.

In other words, nothing is entirely certain. Something entirely different *could* have happened, depending on subtle and perhaps ultimately unknowable factors.

Comment: Tying in with the choice aspect; during the King's Cross chapter in Deathly hallows Dumbledore explains that Harry could board a train that would take him 'on'... and presumably remain dead. It is possible that Harry chose to remain dead in the alternate reality.

Answer (score 3):

### TLDR; Because Neville didn't kill Nagini Voldemort was un-killable.

They state that Harry dies because Cedric Diggory kills Neville. This means the whole battle of Hogwarts is thrown off as now Voldemort still has his remaining Horcrux in Nagini, while we don't know exactly what happens, assuming that Harry and Voldemort still have the same show down in the woods, and Voldemorts Soul fragment is removed from Harry, they are no longer tied together anymore, and Voldemort or anyone else for that matter can kill Harry, while Voldemort can still be "killed" but has 1 horcrux left to re-resurrect himself with.

> **Snape:** Cedric Diggory killed only one wizard and not a significant one — Neville >!Longbottom. 
>
>  **SCORPIUS:** Oh, of course, that’s it! Professor Longbottom was supposed
>  to kill Nagini, Voldemort’s snake. Nagini had to die before Voldemort
>  could die. That’s it! You’ve solved it! We destroyed Cedric, he killed
>  Neville, Voldemort won the battle. Can you see? Can you see it?

Despite everything else the fact that Nagini didn't die throws off the entire fight, we don't know Exactly what happens but that is why Voldemort lives, and Harry dies.

**Voldemort is not limited to Aveda Kedarva to kill Harry.**

Since Nagini is not dead, Voldemort could simply use Nagini to kill him. Harry can still die, despite Voldemort being alive, Voldemort just probably cant kill him personally.

Its also not clear that Voldemort killed Harry, just that he is dead.

> Have you swallowed something funny in there? Become a Mudblood without any of us noticing? Harry Potter died over twenty years ago as part of that failed coup on the school — he was one of those Dumbledore terrorists we bravely overthrew at the Battle of Hogwarts. Now come along — I don’t know what game you’re playing but you’re upsetting the dementors and entirely ruining Voldemort Day.

Comment: But none of that has anything to do with the sacrificial blood protection that ran through Harry and Voldemort's veins, and kept Harry alive. Nagini has absolutely nothing to do with the blood protection to tethered Harry to life.

Comment: @Zack based on this http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35074/why-didnt-harry-die-in-the-dark-forest it agree's with you, so we must assume this is a retcon plain and simple. we are lead to believe that its specifically due to Nevilles death.

Comment: This is not the only retcon were stuck with, remeber that somehow they were all able to see the potters house that was under Fiduleos charm

Comment: All is explained in the companion novel: "Enoby u were almost shot!11" said Serious. "But da ballet could not kill u since u were form anodder time."

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/can-voldemort-kill-harry says that voldemort can kill harry in other ways

Comment: I have read that in the graveyard, he could have used somebody else's blood to bring himself back. I also read that after Harry failed to kill Voldemort in the Battle of Hogwarts, he could have used somebody's else's blood to build himself a brand new body. But I thought Harry died during the Battle of Hogwarts in the alternate reality...

Comment: @Zack Harry does die in the battle of hogwarts in the alternate reality, we just dont know if voldemort personally killed him. Voldemort could have Also used anothers blood but Harry would have still ended up winning the tri-wizard cup and ending up in the graveyard with voldemort so he probably still used Harrys blood.

Comment: Serious question: would Voldemort actually use anything but his own hands (..well, wand) to kill Harry? I doubt it very much. Then again it's said that he had a child with Bella despite the fact Bella wasn't at all described to be pregnant... Not to mention that Voldemort wouldn't have had any of that nonsense.

Comment: In the prime reality, Neville killed Nagini because Harry told him to. If Neville had been killed by Cedric, Harry would have asked someone else to kill Nagini.

Answer (score -1):

The body that Voldemort made for himself WAS destroyed by Harry.

Maybe since Voldemort's soul was in Nagini, it killed Harry.